# Accessing nginx index.html on EC2

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to stand up an EC2 instance with elastic search using nginx as an front end node access point. I used this tutorial to set it up.

```
http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/setting-nginx-plus-environment-amazon-ec2/
```

According to it I should be able to "check it by pointing your web browser to the public DNS name of your newborn EC2 instance."

But when I go to the ec2 domain in a browser I get json of the cluster status.

I have an index.html that I've place in /var/www/index.html but I am unable to access it from a browser.

Comment: should be `/var/www/html/index.html`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what I did wrong but I used this example instead and it's all working ok.

http://www.comtechies.com/2014/03/How-to-install-and-configure-nginx-on-amazon-ec2.html